# Mysql get current count till result

Tags: mysql, sql, date, mysql-5.6

This is my data set:

```
id  user_id amount  added   
1   1   10.00   2018-09-11  
2   2   10.00   2018-09-12
3   3   10.00   2018-09-13
4   1   8.00    2018-09-14
5   2   6.00    2018-09-15
```

What I need is a query to produce the following result:

```
id  user_id amount  added   status
1   1   10.00   2018-09-11  new
2   2   10.00   2018-09-12  new
3   3   10.00   2018-09-13  new
4   1   8.00    2018-09-14  recurring
5   2   6.00    2018-09-15  recurring
```

I want to get status of user id either previous it occurred or not. If not than show `new` else `recurring`.

Comment: Which MySQL? MySQL 8.0 has some tasty new functions that make this much easier.

Comment: @Amadan no, its mysql 5.6

Comment: There are many ways to solve this. The question can be worded as "does the user exist in previous records", which would be solved with `EXISTS` or `IN`. Or we could say "is this date the first date a user occurs at" which may be solved with `MIN`. You, however, have shown no attempt, not even an idea how to tacke this. Next time please try something yourself and only come here when you get stuck. Then show your algorithm or query and tell us what you tried and what exactly isn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply `JOIN` with grouped data:

```
SELECT
    userdata.*,
    CASE WHEN userdata.added = groupsq.first_date THEN 'new' ELSE 'recurring' END AS status
FROM userdata
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT user_id, MIN(added) AS first_date
    FROM userdata
    GROUP BY user_id
) AS groupsq ON userdata.user_id = groupsq.user_id
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to know whether a record's date is the minimum date for the user:

```
select id, user_id, amount, added,
  case when (user_id, added) in (select user_id, min(added) from mytable group by user_id)
    then 'new' else 'recurring' as status
from mytable
order by id;
```

The same can of course be done by joining the subquery instead or by using a correlated `EXISTS` clause. And as of MySQL 8.0 I'd use `MIN() OVER()`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this query:

```
select @user_id_lag := 0;
select id, user_id, amount, added, status from (
    select case when @user_id_lag = user_id then 'recurring' else 'new' end status,
           @user_id_lag := user_id user_id,
           id, amount, added
    from tbl
    order by user_id, added
) a order by added
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f5b734/6)

Answer (score 1):

Try below: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6ef4c6/11

```
select *, case when num=1 then 'New' when num=2 then 'Recurring' end as status from 
(SELECT id,
    @row_number:=CASE
        WHEN @customer_no = userid THEN @row_number + 1
        ELSE 1
    END AS num,
    @customer_no:=userid as CustomerNumber

FROM
    test, (SELECT @customer_no:=0,@row_number:=0) as t
ORDER BY userid)a
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id,user_id , amount , added    , 'new' AS status FROM new_table GROUP BY user_id
UNION ALL 
SELECT id, user_id , amount , added    , 'recursive' AS status FROM new_table 
WHERE id  NOT IN (SELECt * FROM ( SELECT idnew_table FROM   new_table GROUP BY user_id ) AS t )
```